# PhantomJS - pass buffer when function expects file path

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

How to pass a buffer to a function instead of passing a file path?

This doesn't work (it's a bug) so I need another way to pass a buffer to the first argument which sends to stdout, but how?

```
page.render('/dev/stdout', {format : 'pdf'});
```

I can do something like this, but don't want to create a file

```
var pdf_file = 'test.pdf';
page.render(pdf_file, {format : 'pdf'});
var pdf = fs.read(pdf_file);
require('system').stdout.write(pdf);
fs.remove(pdf_file);
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me. Could you add a little more detail ?

Comment: updated........

Comment: also in PhantomJS?

Comment: idea was to recommend a look at using node.stream .. did not mean to distract w/ ref to express. It was where there was example that IMO was relevant. I looked at ur code and the use of FS and occurred that a stream may fit your requirement in diff way. buffer to stream is diff part of api than FS